# sending a email by the use of a variable

Tags: php, email

I have search for my problem and i know there is a easy fix for it but i just can't figure it out and i keep banging my head against the wall, so here goes:

i have a variable in my config file

```
$businessemail = "me@myemail.com";
```

This email changes a lot so i want to use this variable in my mail script which is this

```
    //If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = '$businessemail'; //Put your own email address here
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nComments:\n $comments";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;
}
```

}

Now my question is how do i format the $businessemail in the right way so it can read and sent the message to the email in the config file

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `$businessemail` in line 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
$emailTo = $businessemail; // don't use variable in single quotes here
```

Comment: Thank you Pekka that was it... you really helped me out here :-))